# Bluetooth Assistant keeps popping up!

Tags: bluetooth

On my Mac, whenever I turn it on, the Bluetooth Setup Assistant automatically pops up. I always have my Bluetooth on, on my phone. Could that be why?
Also, when I turn off the bluetooth on my phone, the Assistant doesn't go away. It only goes away if I unplug my mouse and plug it back in.

It keeps searching for bluetooth keyboard and mouse for some reason.

iMac is on Mojave (latest versions)
My mouse is a Macally Mouse

Comment: It sounds like the iMac doesn't think there are any keyboards or mice connected when it starts up. Are either of the mouse or keyboard wireless?

Comment: Neither are. Both are wired.

Comment: Try unchecking the option to open the bluetooth input device setup if no devices are detected anyway. System Preferences > Bluetooth > Advanced

Answer (score 2):

Turning off the bluetooth settings seemed to work!